# .NET Core System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, .net-core, iis

I'm trying to write a file to a `pdf` folder under `wwwroot` but I get an error

> UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied

I'm using the iText library

```
    private readonly IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment;
    private string webRootPath;
    private string contentRootPath;
    private string path;

    public Pdf(IWebHostEnvironment webHostEnvironment)
    {
        this.webHostEnvironment = webHostEnvironment;
        webRootPath = webHostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
        contentRootPath = webHostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;
        path = Path.Combine(contentRootPath, "wwwroot", "pdf");
    }

    public void CreatePDF()
    {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(new PdfWriter(new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)));
        Document document = new Document(pdfDocument);

        String line = "Hello! Welcome to iTextPdf";
        document.Add(new Paragraph(line));
        document.Close();

        Console.WriteLine("Awesome PDF just got created.");
    }
```

In .NET 4.6, giving write permissions to `IIS_IUSRS` under the Security tab of the system folder used to resolve writing issues.

What's the equivalent procedure and user object for .NET Core?

[image]

I'm running my project on Windows 10 with Visual Studio 2022 and the launch profile for debugging under project properties is "Project".

[image]

Comment: You'd better first use Process Monitor to learn what's the actual file path giving you the error.

Comment: Access to the file is denied indicates that the location doesn’t exist, or because the authenticating user does not have any permissions applied to write to this location.